# How to repair stripped drywall anchor

Tags: walls

I took a blind down a while back to decorate the spare room. Before moving it I noticed that one of the wall plugs was loose. I replaced it with a brown wall plug but it's going straight into the ceiling and disappearing.

My thoughts is that my landlord has drilled in the wrong area. I have put a really long screw in to test and it just keeps going all the way up.

I can't screw into the wall plug as the plug just goes too far into the wall and doesn't grip on to anything.

I don't know how to fix this :/

Comment: What is a "Wall Plug"? Do you mean a drywall anchor?

Comment: @longneck I'm not sure what they might be called elsewhere, but in the UK, wall plugs are [these](http://www.diy.com/departments/rawlplug-plastic-wall-plug-pack-of-288/255096_BQ.prd).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong size plug. Measure the hole, go to the hardware store (ironmongers?) and buy the appropriate plug for your hole size. Also, make sure you are using the proper size screw for the plug. If the screw diameter is too small, it will not expand the plug and it will not grip tightly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the plug onto the end of a screw so that it starts to expand the plug a little and see if that will grip the side of the hole. (You might then need to give it a tap with a hammer to drive the plug home).

I've also seen a roll up plastic material that you can use to make larger "custom" plugs than the standard sizes. You roll it up to fit the hole, then cut it off at the surface.